Debugging VSCode .ipynb cell that implicitly invokes IPython.display raises AttributeError
My class C overrides __getattr__.
In my .ipynb cell, I do c = C() ; c
If I run this cell, it works. But if I debug it, I now hit an AttributeError exception.

How to deal with this?
PS Crossreferencing:

What is "_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_"?
How do I override __getattr__ without breaking the default behavior?

PPS I'll attempt to answer my own question below.

What's the AttributeError? What's C's implementation of __getattr__()? Please provide a [mre].

@wjandrea Added...

Please provide text as text. The screenshot might include additional context, so no need to remove it, just make sure all the important text is included in written form.

I suspect the line c invokees IPython.display which probes for certain attributes IPython has added.
If we weren't overriding __getattr__, we'd be unaware of this.
Dumping them out (with a print(k) at the top of my `get_attr' override):
    _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
    _ipython_display_
    _repr_mimebundle_
    _repr_html_
    _repr_markdown_
    _repr_svg_
    _repr_png_
    _repr_pdf_
    _repr_jpeg_
    _repr_latex_
    _repr_json_
    _repr_javascript_

Presumably IPython.display, which was invoked by my single line c, checks for the presence of these attributes using try/except and catching the AttributeError exception.
The problem is that now I'm overriding __getattr__, the exception now occurs from WITHIN MY CODE!
And so, even if I catch these accesses (if k.startswith('_'): ...), whether I:
(1) attempt to fall-back to object.__getattribute__(self, k), or:
(2) raise AttributeError,
... an AttributeError exception is thrown that now qualifies as "User Uncaught Exception".
It seems my options are:

return without raising (if k.startswith('_'): return). This feels sketchey, as IPython.display is likely being deprived of the AttributeError exception it's hoping for (if my guess that this is what it is indeed doing is correct),
Use print statements, so that IPython.display isn't invoked, or:
Un-checking "Raised Exceptions" and "User Uncaught Exceptions" in the breakpoints tab of the VSCode debugger pane, in which case I can raise or fallback.

Tentatively, I suspect the correct path is:
    def __getattr__(self, k):
        if k.startswith('_'):
            return

